# How do I add Netbeans to the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

I have installed NetBeans 7.0 manually, because only 6.9 is available in Ubuntu Software Center.

I tried to keep it in launcher, but after system restart it's gone.

How can I permanently add it?

Comment: netbeans 8.2 creates a desktop configuration file in $HOME/.local/share/applications

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a netbeans.desktop file with somewhat following content in your `$HOME/.local/share/applications/` folder(If not present create it). And drag and drop the netbeans.desktop file to your launcher. I am doing the same with eclipse. If you want netbeans to be available to othe users as well you can create the desktop file in `/usr/share/applications` as well.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Netbeans
Comment=Netbeans IDE
Exec=path/to/executable i.e. $HOME/netbeans/netbeans
Icon=netbeans
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development,IDE;
StartupNotify=false
```

Make sure you have correct path and keep in launcher is checked.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already have netbeans-7.0.desktop file with content - cat netbeans-7.0.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=NetBeans IDE 7.0
Comment=The Smarter Way to Code
Exec=/bin/sh "/home/umpirsky/Applications/netbeans-7.0/bin/netbeans"
Icon=/home/umpirsky/Applications/netbeans-7.0/nb/netbeans.png
Categories=Application;Development;Java;IDE
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=0

Comment: Installs `dconf-tools`  and run `dconf-editor` and on desktop>unity> favourites section see if netbeans is there or not. You can add netbeans.desktop path there and set it to default may be.

Comment: Thanks again. It is not there. Isn't this a bug?

Comment: add it and see if it exists or not after logout. It may be a bug.

Comment: Does not exist. Reported https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/785095

Comment: My bad, duplicated https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bamf/+bug/754334

Answer (score 9):

'Java Ayatana' plugin for Netbeans solve the following problems ( tested on 12.04 64bit)

- adds global menu
- fixes launcher

How to install:

**1)**
in Tools -> Plugins -> Settings
 add  http://java-swing-ayatana.googlecode.com/files/netbeans-catalog.xml

now look for:
 'Java Ayatana' Tools -> plugin -> Avariable plugin

**2)**
or install manually from:
 http://code.google.com/p/java-swing-ayatana/

**On 64bit** with oracle java 7 if you experience this problem:

`libjawt.so cannot open shared object file no such file`

do this:

`sudo ldconfig /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/`

Thank you Dan Jaren for this plugin

**Update:**

On NetBeans 7.2RC1 launcher works fine by default.
'Java Ayatana' 's global menu integration works fine too.

Comment: I installed it and now my NetBeans is broken. Crashes after startup. Any idea how I can remove this plugin by hand?

Comment: People, don't install this! I installed it and now I can't run NetBeans at all.

Comment: Fixed, thanks to https://blogs.oracle.com/gridbag/entry/disabling_a_netbeans_plugin_before

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 12.04 64bit, I can confirm this:http://code.google.com/p/java-swing-ayatana/ is working
I have Netbeans menu as global menu and the icon in the launcer.
So it is perfectly integrated 
Please remove -1 vote.

Note:
I have java 7 from sun and I had to do that :

    sudo ldconfig /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/

Comment: OK, I removed -1 vote, but I'll not risk again :)

Comment: Thank you,
Don't know what was the problem you encountered maybe if you post more detail you can get support ... 
You can also post on the dev blog
http://danjared.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/integrando-java-con-ubuntu-netbeans/

Comment: @Postadelmaga What version of Netbeans are you using? 7.0.1 or 7.1.2?

Comment: @Hanynowsky
I'm using:  
    Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.1 (Build 201112071828)  
    Java: 1.7.0_04; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.0-b21

Comment: @Postadelmaga ok thanks. I wanted to make sure if it was version specific. I updated the info on : http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/integration-of-java-swing-applications-with-unity-global-menu-in-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: I approve that this is only working with openJDK 7 and not openJDK 6.If you have installed Netbeans with 6 and want it to use 7, you will have to edit the $NETBEANS_INSTALL_DIR/etc/netbeans.conf. Locate the  netbeans_jdkhome-line and add the line to the openJDK 7, in my case that's "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64". If you're not sure where to locate openJDK 7, you could have a look at "update-alternatives --list java".

Comment: It isn't working on Ubuntu 13.10 32-bits. I'm using NetBeans 7.2, and oracle jdk 1.6. On Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04 versions, it was working fine.

Comment: Doesn't work on my laptop :( I'm using Netbeans 7.4. java version "1.6.0_27". `update-alternatives --list java` shows me
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`

Comment: I updated java to 1.7.0_45. Still doesn't work... `update-alternatives --list java` shows `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java`

Answer (score 6):

The answer of Kacharov is good (very good), but the Ubuntu Unity Launcher Plugin of Netbeans is already on Netbeans plugin and Google project website.

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40321/ubuntu-unity-launcher
http://code.google.com/p/nbs-unity-launcher/

To make it more formal.

Comment: Hi, This plugin is obsolete, I recommend removing this plugin and install a new Java Ayatana Plugin http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/41822

Answer (score 5):

Following @sagarchalise's answer, here's a working (**~/.local/share/applications/netbeans.desktop**) contents for **NB 7.0.1** on Ubuntu 11.04:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Netbeans
Comment=Netbeans IDE
Exec=/usr/local/netbeans-7.0.1/bin/netbeans
Icon=/usr/local/netbeans-7.0.1/nb/netbeans.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development,IDE;
StartupNotify=false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this NetBeans plugin!

http://ubuntuone.com/4T3EB9MnJVqxrEE494oLyi

It is very useful!

Original page: http://danjared.blogspot.com/2011/10/unity-launcher.html

Comment: Yes, I use it already. But what to do with tvtime or gedit when you open some text file from remote location from nautilus. Same problem occurs. This should be fixed in unity, as in other launchers for ubuntu.

Comment: Still problems after upgrade to NetBeans 7.1, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in BAMF:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bamf/+bug/754334

Comment: I wonder will someone fix this...

Answer (score 0):

I am on Ubuntu 14.10 with Netbeans 8.0 and Docky 2.0

I was able to solve the problem by doing the following steps from: http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=How_to_Customize_Window_Matching

1 Create netbeans.desktop file for Netbeans something like this (adjust for your netbeans path, version, etc.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Netbeans 8.0
Comment=Java IDE
Exec=/bin/sh "/home/your/path/to/netbeans/bin/netbeans"
Icon=/home/your/path/to/netbeans/nb/ntebeans.png
Categories=Application;Development;Java;IDE
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=0
StartupWMClass=REPLACE_ME
```

2 Start Netbeans

3 Open a terminal window and run:

```
xprop | grep WM_CLASS | awk '{print $4}'
```

4 A crosshair cursor will be displayed, click on netbeans window

The WMClass for the window should be printed in terminal, for me this was:

```
"netbeans-8.0"
```

6 In the netbeans.desktop set the value for StartupWMClass like so:

```
StartupWMClass=netbeans-8.0
```

7 Save the file and copy to;

```
/usr/share/applications
```

8 Exit Docky

8.5 optional step: delete the docky desktop cache in

```
~/.cache/docky/docky.desktop.*.cache
```

9 Start Docky

10 Drag your netbeans.desktop file from /usr/share/applcations in nautilus (etc.) into docky

11 Start up netbeans and see what happens :D

Answer (score 0):

For the current NetBeans 11 version, installed in /opt

Also changed the default icon from the tiny .png file meant for Windows, to the larger .icns file meant for MacOSX. This looks much better in the launcher. Also had to fix the StartupMWClass= to prevent 2 icons from showing.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Apache NetBeans IDE 11.0
Keywords=cpp,java
Exec=/opt/netbeans/bin/netbeans
Icon=/opt/netbeans/nb/netbeans.icns
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development,Java,IDE
StartupWMClass=Apache NetBeans IDE 11.0
```

Just save the above as ~/.local/share/applications/netbeans.desktop